# Laravel event before mail sent and get TO email address

Tags: laravel, email, events

is there any event that is being called before mail sent? what I am trying to do is, I have a whitelist of emails. So need to check in the event that if the email is in the whitelist only then send the email otherwise not. Tried this event

`Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending`

but this event does not provide TO email but just data and message

```
public function __construct($message, $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
```

Comment: can you see if `$message->getTo()` has the address?

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, it worked

$message = $event->message;
$addresses = $message->getTo();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        $message = $event->message;
        $addresses = $message->getTo();
        print_r($addresses);
    }
```

This worked for me